# Is here any standard CRS name for plain 2D data aka non-Earth projection?

Tags: coordinates, gis

I'm interested in using different geotools for work with spatial data, but without Earth projection, plain 2D like big game maps. But I'm struggling each time to configure a tool that way.

Hence the question: does exist some standard projection name for GDAL, MariaDB, etc? I've tried to find any, but no luck. This seems strange, might be a quite common user case.

Comment: Note; having a CRS name doesn't mean there is a conversion function on most tools. You can also just specify yourself the parameter of such "projection", we have not much information: it is a torus (like PacMan?) or it can go to infinity? What about just using one of the many x,y coordinates (so metric, not angles)? [just set boundaries]

Comment: Since you couldn't convert to any other projection there is no point in picking a projection if you have none. GeoServer uses EPSG:404000 for a default null projection but I don't think anyone else uses it too.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm talking about plain 2d, just infinite orthogonal x,y. No any exotics like torus or polar coordinate system. Sure, I can specify parameters of such "projection", but it seems more hard and done in different ways in tools. Just specifying by name usually way simpler.

Comment: @IanTurton Yes, defaults is another thing I'm worried about. If a tool is using some default reasonable for Earth projection, it may affect accuracy and result in some bugs. Also I have to transfer data between different tools, so I have to specify something meaningful to avoid distortion. Some tools may just require it.

Comment: But so, you cannot use regular geotools, they expect some cyclicity, and not infinite numbers (you lose precision quickly going far from center

Comment: In my use case precision in enough, I'm not using huge numbers anyway. The whole map is +/- 5000 units from the center. But is has a lot of polygons marking different terrains or areas with some objects, hence interest in such tools for map authoring, presentation, best path finding, etc. No need to re-invent wheel.